# javascript code hide all my site

Tags: javascript, html

i have one problem. I have a website host on altervista.com, and now I want to add advertising . But there is a problem , when I insert the script that automatically provides me altervista in one part of my site , updating the website page you see only the advertising disappears and the rest of the site .
the javascript is this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
document.write('<s'+'cript type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.altervista.org/js.ad/size=300X250/r='+new Date().getTime()+'"><\/s'+'cript>');
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

If I insert the code at the start of `<head>` , advertising displays and even the site , but advertising is rightly displayed so misaligned than other things the site .
No one can explain why?

Comment: Wow, that script is bad. It injects code directly into your page. A script like this can allow the advertiser to steal sensitive information from your users.  I would look for a possibility to load the ad in an iframe. That will also solve your positioning issue, since you can position the iframe anywhere you like.

Comment: i can't add it in a frame. There are other methods? @GolezTrol

Comment: Why not? I don't think there are other ways that provide the same level of security.

Comment: because if i insert it in a frame the provide as counts the advertising  down to the site and there are gains less. @GolezTrol 
I have find the error, there are a conflict with my unit.js file and it use jquery. I have use the jquery noconflicts(); but don't work.

Comment: Okay. Then please tell me what your site is, so I can make sure never to visit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that code directly in-line where you want the advertising to be.

Comment: in your HTML where you want your advertising to show up. Insert that code.